# Visual Studio 2019 project turned all into indention

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, project

my whole python project in visual studio turned into weird **symbols** [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkweP.jpg)  which when I copy and paste reads as indention, I saved the project before putting my laptop to sleep mode and this happened, how do I fix that and evade this from happening again

Comment: Don't let your cat sleep on your laptop! Joking aside, when you returned to your reawakened laptop did you save what looked like odd unexpected changes?

Comment: If you saved it as you say, then you should be able to just close it now **without saving** and reopen it. If that doesn't work, you're out of luck unless you're using a version control system that you can get a copy from.

Comment: I didn't save the unexpected changes although it still damaged after reopening it, why did that happen and how can I prevent that from happening again,thanks in advance